# Makes steps hesitantly with fear

Tags: word-request

Is the word to describe when one walks hesitantly with fear? For example, in the below sentence I'm sure there will be a better way to write if there is a word to describe hesitantly with fear.

```
He makes steps hesitantly with fear.
```

Comment: I believe that it would be easier for others to make good suggestions if you could be more specific about what he fears.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Let's say he wants to talk to a group of really bad people (gangsters). He sees them little far standing as a group, and wants to talk to them, but he is afraid that they might beat him.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase it with simple words. Here is my take: *He walks carefully, trying to avoid drawing any possible attention to himself.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. This is too long. I generally like small sentences. Plus, your sentence doesn't really express that he is scared and fearful.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I felt "He steps warily" seems better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible word: *warily*. It is the adverbial form of *wary*.

He walked *warily* into the dark, scary room. *Wary* has more to do with caution and looking out and not necessarily fear, but it can include fear.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can express the idea of your sentence with the word **creep**.

According to Cambridge Dictionary, it is defined as:

> To move slowly, quietly, and carefully, usually in order to avoid being noticed

Definition [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/creep_1).

You can combine this word with your sentence to make something that probably fits your needs, e.g:

> He creeps with fear

Answer (score 1):

Warily is an excellent word, as Wally has said.  Gingerly also comes to mind.  Looking up warily in the thesaurus also reveals guardedly and cautiously, as well as numerous other words with less similar meanings.

Comment: I don't find even a single match for this phrase in Google. "He makes steps warily". Why?  Check here https://www.google.com/search?q=%22makes+steps+warily%22&oq=%22makes+steps+warily%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.629j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @T2E the problem is not with 'warily', 'cautiously' or other synonyms (I'd use fearfully) combined with steps, but with 'makes steps' this in not idiomatic (when describing how someone walks). That is why the search is getting no hits.